# Sigma algebra with symmetric difference and measure proof

Tags: measure-theory

Let X be artbitrary set, $\mathcal{F}$ sigma algebra on X and $\mu$ a measure and:
$$
\mathcal{N} = \left\{ N \subset X: \exists F\in \mathcal{F}: \mu(F) = \text{0  }  \wedge N \subset F \right\}
$$
$$
 \overline{\mathcal{F}}= \left\{F \bigtriangleup N : F \in \mathcal{F}, N \in \mathcal{N} \right\}
$$

Show that $$
\overline{\mathcal{F}}=\sigma(\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{N})$$

I know that $\mathcal{N}$ is a sigma-ring:

- $\emptyset \in \mathcal{N}$ trivially
- Let $A, B \in \mathcal{N}$. Then $A\setminus{B} = A \cap B^{C} \subset A \subset F$ for some $F \in \mathcal{F}$. So $A\setminus{B} \in \mathcal{N}$
- Let $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{N}$. Then $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty}A_n \subset \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty}F_n$. But $ \mu\left({\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty}F_n}\right) \leq \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty}\mu(F_n) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty}0 = 0$. So countable sums also belong to $\mathcal{N}$.

Now, taking arbitrary $A \in \overline{\mathcal{F}}$:
$$
A = F \bigtriangleup N = F\setminus{N} \text{ }\cup \text{ } N\setminus{F}
$$
But $F\setminus{N} \in \sigma(\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{N})$ and so does $N\setminus{F}$ and so does their sum.

Is above partial-proof correct? How can I proceed with $\sigma(\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{N}) \subset \overline{\mathcal{F}}$?

Comment: The partial proof above seems correct, by adding missing $\exists F_n\in\mathcal F:A_n\subseteq F_n$ to the third item in the list. And for $\sigma(\mathcal F \cup \mathcal N)\subset \overline{\mathcal F}$, you may use $\pi-\lambda$ theorem.

Comment: Unfortunately, we haven't introduced $\pi - \lambda$ theorem.

Comment: Oh, in this case $\overline{\mathcal F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. First try to show this directly, using similar method with the one in your proof that $\mathcal N$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then recall the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set $\mathcal A$ of subsets: $$ \sigma(\mathcal A)= \bigcap_{(\mathcal A\subseteq) \mathcal F:\sigma\text{-algebra}}\mathcal F $$
then you will see that it suffices to show that $\overline{\mathcal F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\mathcal F \cup \mathcal N$.

Comment: Taking N = $\emptyset$ and $F \in \mathcal{F}$ or $F = \emptyset$ with $N \in \mathcal{N}$ I can prove that both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are in $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$. Because $\sigma({\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{N}}$) is the smallest sigma algebra containing them we know it is $\subset \overline{\mathcal{F}}$. I am stuck on proving that $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ is indeed a sigma algebra though. $\emptyset$ and $X$ are easy, I am not sure how to tackle complement and countable sums though.

Comment: Or perhaps: Let $A \in \overline{F}$. Then $A^{C} = (F \bigtriangleup N)^{C} = ((F\cup N)\setminus(F \cap N))^C = \dots = (F^C \setminus N) \cup (F \cap N ).$ But $F^C \setminus N \in \mathcal{F}$ and $F \cap N \in \mathcal{F}$. And since $\mathcal{F} \in \overline{\mathcal{F}}$ we have $A^C \in \overline{\mathcal{F}}$. Is that correct proof for complement?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. For the countable union, we have $F_i\cup N_i = F_i \bigtriangleup (N_i\setminus F_i) \in \overline{\mathcal F}$. Then $\bigcup (F_i\cup N_i') = \bigcup F_i \cup \bigcup N_i'$ where $\bigcup N_i'=\bigcup(N_i\setminus F_i)$ is contained in a larger set whose measure is 0...